# Elegant way for quick IF statement in blade

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, web, laravel-blade

I´m new to Laravel and I know I can echo variables within double curly brackets like this:

```
<p>{{ $posts->id }}</p>
```

Now in my case I have a form that sometimes contains the variable $posts (which is the table by the way) to update and sometimes doesn´t contain it to insert a row depending on the parameters in the URL.

Of course if there is no post then the part "->id" will fail.
Is there an elegant way to make a quick IF statement here, like:

```
<?php if ($posts) echo $posts["id"]; ?>
```

but just using the blade engine.

I know I can use @if around the HTML-block but then I would have to write that block twice all the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what exactly is `$posts`.

You can use ternary statement. For example, if `$posts` is collection or array, use `empty`:

```
{{ empty($posts) ? '' : $posts->id }}
```

If it's just variable, use `isset()`

In some cases can use `or` syntax:

```
{{ $posts or 'It is empty' }}
```

In PHP7 you can use `??` (null coalescing operator) to check if variable `isset()`. For example:

```
{{ $posts ?? $posts->id }}
```

You can see another explanation in [the official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#displaying-data) (see `Echoing Data If It Exists` part).

Comment: $posts is the result of Post::findOrFail which I believe is just JSON, Post is my model representing a database table.

Comment: `findOrFail()` returns an exception if no post found. Use `find()` or `where()->first()` instead which will return `null`. In this case you'll be able to use ternary operator `{{ is_null($post) ? '' : $post->id }}`

Comment: `findOrFail()` won't return json; it will return an object (or throw an exception on fail)

Answer (score 1):

Another and more "laravel-like" way to do it is [optional](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-optional) helper.

```
{{ optional($posts)->id }}
```

Works great in conjuration with `old` helper.